# Angular async pipe reduces stream value rather than displays latest emission

Tags: angular, rxjs6, angular-pipe

My useage of `mergeMap` seems to reduce the boolean stream down to one value, because

```
<button [disabled]="!(canRequestPricing$ | async)"
```

`canRequestPricing$ | async` should be true, but if the first emission is false, it is false.

```
public canRequestPricing$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);


public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.canRequestPricingSubscription = this.canRequestPricing$.pipe(
        mergeMap(() => this.mappedItem.canRequestPricing()),
        take(1),
        mergeMap((canRequestPricingFromApi) => {
            const can = this.canRequestPricing() && canRequestPricingFromApi;
            return of(can);
        })).subscribe();
}
```

since the emitter initialises with false, the `(canRequestPricing$ | async)` amounts to false. When I initialise it with `true` then `(canRequestPricing$ | async)` amounts to true.

`const can = this.canRequestPricing() && canRequestPricingFromApi;` always is true which is correct, and I just need the initialsed `false` of `public canRequestPricing$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);` to not effect the final value.

I want the behaviour to be that `(canRequestPricing$ | async)` amounts to whatever the last emission was. How do I get that behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, `canRequestPricing$` is dependent on `this.canRequestPricing()` and `this.mappedItem.canRequestPricing()`.

```
this.mappedItem.canRequestPricing().pipe(
  take(1),
  map(canRequestPricingFromApi => this.canRequestPricing() && canRequestPricingFromApi)
).subscribe(can => {
  this.canRequestPrincing$.next(can);
})
```